# How to pass a byte[] parameter type in a sql query in MyBatis?

Tags: mybatis

I need to match against an encrypted column in the DB. I need to pass the encrypted value for matching as a byte[]. The hashcode of the byte[] is passed instead of the actual value stored in the byte[]. Because the hash code is passed, it does not match the value correctly. Below is my query and the function call in the Mapper.java.

```
AccBalNotificationBean selectAccBalNotificationBean(@Param("acctIdByteArray") byte[] acctIdByteArray);

SELECT toa.accounts_id from tbl_transactions_other_accounts toa WHERE other_account_number = #{acctIdByteArray}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the datatype of your other_account_number column is of type string (char, varchar etc). Mybatis will use the StringDataTypeHandler by default and call the .toString() method of your byte array. Give MyBatis a hint that you want the content of your array to be used, by specifying the typeHandler.

```
.. WHERE other_account_number = #{acctIdByteArray, typeHandler=org.apache.ibatis.type.ByteArrayTypeHandler}
```

Comment: This worked for me using MySql and binary columns (UUIDs).  
Interesting note: on another project using a different database engine (MS SQL and jTDS driver), specifying `typeHandler=org.apache.ibatis.type.ByteArrayTypeHandler` was not required.  The jTDS driver must handle that conversion whereas MySQL and its driver didn't work.  When I say it didn't, it would not return any result.